# Можно ли место уточнять временем и как ставить запятые, если речь идет только о времени?

Tags: пунктуация

Хочу раз и навсегда прояснить для себя вопрос, как поступать в следующих случаях?

1) Если речь идет о двух уточняющих обстоятельствах места и времени. Напр. В Петербурге в 20.00...

2) Если речь идет только об обстоятельствах времени. Напр. В воскресенье, 11 января в 20:00... Сегодня, 30 декабря в 20:00... 28 декабря в 16:00...

Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформление предложений такого вида является авторским, здесь возможны разные варианты (неоднородные, уточняющие или даже однородные члены).

1) Неоднородные (определение координат: день недели, число, время): "В воскресенье 11 января в 20.00 состоится концерт".

2) Уточняющие (уточнение дня):"В воскресенье, 11 января, в 20.00 состоится концерт".

3) Однородные (перечисление координат): "В воскресенье, 11 января, в 20.00 состоится концерт".

Вот только после 20.00 запятую ставить нежелательно, так как мы уточняем только день, а не час. К тому же назначение запятых тогда тоже неясно (общее обособление не отличается от перечисления  внутри обособленного оборота).

Comment: Т.е. между датой и временем в любом случае должны стоять запятые... Понятно. Спасибо. А как быть с "28 декабря в 16:00"? Их можно рассматривать как однородные члены?

Comment: Наиболее приемлемый вариант с уточнением дня: "В воскресенье, 11 января, в 20.00 состоится концерт". Остальные (1 и 3) тоже возможны, но используются реже. Наличие вариантов связано с тем, что автор по своему усмотрению может представить обстоятельства как однородные, неоднородные, уточняющие, в каждом случае приведя обоснование. Таким образом, можно пользоваться вариантами и при этом (что важно) оставаться в рамках правил

Comment: И чем это отличается от розенталевского "Он встал по хозяйству рано, в третьем часу утра, и теперь у него слипались глаза"? Т.е. можно ли рассматривать это как ряд уточняющих обстоятельств времени, как и писал Виктор1799?

Comment: В этом примере обязательное пояснение,  так как "рано"  может пониматься по-разному и требует расшифровки (это не уточнение/сужение, а именно пояснение). Неоднородные отношения невозможны, выражение без обособления  "рано в третьем часу утра" не имеет смысла.

Comment: Время пишется через двоеточие, а не через точку. Исправьте примеры, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Vera Спасибо за ответ, мне он тоже пригодился. А можете дать ссылку на источник, чтобы я тоже могла его указать в случае спора? Хочу использовать вариант с уточнением дня. Но у Розенталя, кажется, всё запятыми выделяется, поэтому я сюда и пришла.

Answer (score 0):

В предложении "В Петербурге в 20.00" два обстоятельства, но они разные - места и времени. Место нельзя уточнять временем, как и наоборот, поэтому запятая здесь не нужна. Если же речь идет о нескольких обстоятельствах времени, которые  уточняют время, сужая временнЫе рамки, то в этом случае надо ставить запятые: " В воскресенье, 11 января, в 20.00, состоится концерт"

Comment: Это точно? Потому что это взято с сайта, где уже должно было пройти проверку, и там запятых между датой и временем нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое.